# Alarm dialog with sound

Tags: java, android

I am having an alarm dialog popping up when the countdown timer is finished. It's working fine, but when I try to implement sound into the dialog, it's not working. I'm getting a NullPointerException when I'm loading the alarm (with the shared pref number) the user has chosen somewhere else in the app, from the ringtones list. If I just put in a number and not use the SharedPreferences, I get a NullPointerException when I set the data source to the MediaPlayer. This is my code:

```
public class AlarmDialog extends DialogFragment {

MediaPlayer mp;
Context context;
Uri alarmSound;
int alarmChosen;
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LINE 31 sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("AlarmChosen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    alarmChosen = sharedPrefs.getInt("AlarmChosen", 1);
    RingtoneManager ringtoneMgr = new RingtoneManager(context);
    ringtoneMgr.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
    alarmSound = ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(alarmChosen);       

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.reset();
    try {
        LINE 41 mp.setDataSource(alarmSound.toString());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();

    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(
            LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Alarm");
    builder.setMessage("An Alarm by AlarmManager");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}   
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:
LogCat from sharedPrefs error:

```
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): Process: com.adrissa.kitchentimer, PID: 28062
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adrissa.kitchentimer/com.adrissa.kitchentimer.DemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at com.adrissa.kitchentimer.AlarmDialog.onCreateDialog(AlarmDialog.java:31)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
03-07 22:22:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    ... 11 more
```

LogCat from error, when i just insert 0 instead of the number picked in the sharedPrefs.

```
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): Process: com.adrissa.kitchentimer, PID: 30527
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adrissa.kitchentimer/com.adrissa.kitchentimer.DemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.adrissa.kitchentimer.AlarmDialog.onCreateDialog(AlarmDialog.java:41)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
03-07 22:31:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where does your logcat say you're getting the NullPointerException?  Maybe you could post the logcat?

Comment: There you go @ethan123

Comment: cool, so your logcat says it's happening on line 31 in the first case and 41 in the second case.  which line of your code above does this correspond to?

Comment: Thought I explained that well enough in my text, but added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 31 you haven't instantiated context, thus it is null. Try:

```
sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AlarmChosen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

ADDED:
For the error on line 41, I would suggest using a much more compact pattern to achieve what you're trying to do.  Try:

```
alarmSound = ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(alarmChosen);   
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), alarmSound);
r.play();
```

If all you're trying to do is play the sound of the selected ringtone, then that's probably your best bet and shouldn't give you any errors unless the Uri you're retrieving from getRingtoneUri is null, which would mean that alarmChosen is not a valid argument for this method...

Comment: you're still getting the nullpointerexception on line 41? or is it a different error now?

Comment: added to the answer for line 41

Comment: Thank you very much, I am now playing alarms ;)